# Using Cloudformation to Create DynamoDB with composite primary key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

From the command line or the online API, I have no trouble creating a "composite primary key" but when I try to use CloudFormation to do the job for me, I don't see any JSON/YAML that will let me set something called a "composite primary key". The language is completely different so I was hoping someone could guide me as to how I create such a key using Cloudformation.

My best guess is something like the following where I want the composite key to consist of both userId and noteId:

```
  Resources:
    usersTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: notes_serverless
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: userId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: noteId
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: userId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: noteId
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Comment: Can you show the command that you are using to create the table with composite primary key ?

Comment: I just need the correct YAML syntax.  I'm actually using the serverless framework to deploy the cloud formation code. On the web API there is a simple box you check.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is the YAML syntax for DynamoDB table creation with partition and sort keys.

The syntax on OP is almost correct. I have just formatted with proper quotes and rearranged the order of the properties.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources: 
  usersTable: 
    Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
    Properties: 
      AttributeDefinitions: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "userId"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "noteId"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "userId"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        - 
          AttributeName: "noteId"
          KeyType: "RANGE"
      ProvisionedThroughput: 
        ReadCapacityUnits: "5"
        WriteCapacityUnits: "5"
      TableName: "notes_serverless"
```